# Deleting div elements using jquery remove() property seems to have random behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 divs with a checkbox each. When I click the delete button the div with the checked checkbox should be deleted. However the deletion is working in an unpredictable way.Here is my jsfiddle.     http://jsfiddle.net/mftckzaL/ . Please help!

```
  <div class="0" id="res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border- 
  radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
  </div>
  <div class="1" id="res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border- 
  radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
  </div>
  <div class="2" id="res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-
  radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
  </div>
  <div class="3" id="res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-   
  radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
  </div>
  <div class="4" id="res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-   
  radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
  </div>
  <div class="5" id="res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-  
  radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Delete Selection" name="delete_banner_art" id="delete_banner_art" 
  class="delete_banner_art">
```

My JavaScript:

```
$("#delete_banner_art").click(function () {
checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('resolution');
for (var i = (checkboxes.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
        $("." + i).remove();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Define "an unpredictable way" please. And FYI, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: As in delete for some divs works perfectly fine. But some don't get deleted.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the index within the collection `checkboxes` as part of the class to select. But if you delete say `.1`, then all the items after it no longer line up. `.2` is not the third item anymore, it's the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids should be unique, also the for loop should go to `i > 0` not `i >= 0`

http://jsfiddle.net/mftckzaL/2/

```
for (var i = (checkboxes.length - 1); i > 0; i--) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
        $("." + i).remove();
    }
}
```

Here is a better way to delete the selected item

http://jsfiddle.net/mftckzaL/5/

```
$("#delete_banner_art").click(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').parents('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery, *use jQuery*, and employ its selectors, rather than mixing and matching (badly). To simplify your code (invalid HTML aside), I'd suggest:

```
$("#delete_banner_art").click(function () {
    // we find the inputs of type="checkbox", that are checked:
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
    // find the closest ancestor 'div' element:
    .closest('div')
    // and remove those div elements:
    .remove();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mftckzaL/4/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: +1 "If you're using jQuery, use jQuery"  I could not agree more!  It would be simple enough to do in pure js, but if you're using a library then first - learn how to use it, and then - use the damn library!

Answer (score 1):

here

```
for (var i = (checkboxes.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
        $("." + i).remove();
    }
}
```

when you remove a div, you do not change the classes of the other ones, but the increment is updated to the current number of checkboxes.

you'll be able to remove them all starting from the end up, but it will seem unpredictable if you remove one in the list

Answer (score 0):

### Pure JS

(not any longer)

```
// this does not have to be resolved every time you click
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('resolution');

document.getElementById("delete_banner_art").onclick =function () {
    for (var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l; i++) {
        // "condition" is equivalent to "condition == true"
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) { checkboxes[i].parentNode.remove(); }
    }
};
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: OP wants to remove the div...  `if (checkboxes[i].checked) { checkboxes[i].parentNode.remove(); }`

Answer (score 0):

See the fixed JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mftckzaL/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="0 res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution" />
</div>
<div class="1 res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution" />
</div>
<div class="2 res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution" />
</div>
<div class="3 res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
</div>
<div class="4 res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
</div>
<div class="5 res1" style="border:1.5px solid #a1a1a1;width:900px;height:127;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="res1" name="resolution">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Delete Selection" name="delete_banner_art" id="delete_banner_art" class="delete_banner_art">
```

JS:

```
$("#delete_banner_art").click(function () {
    $('.res1').children('input:checked').parent().remove();
});
```

A couple of things however,

1. In the HTML, I changed the repeated id attributes to classes. ID's by nature, are unique and having more than one on a page may cause problems in the future.
2. I don't think classes can start with a number.